# How to consider the bigger date inside groups after summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm taking the mean, 3 by 3, by grouping. For that, I'm using the `summarise` function. In this context I would like to select the last date from the four that make up the average.

I tried to select the maximum, but this way I'm just selecting the highest date for the whole group.

```
test = data.frame(my_groups = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C",  "A", "A", "A"),
                  measure = c(10, 20, 5, 2, 62 ,2, 5, 4, 6, 7, 25),
                  time= c("20-09-2020", "25-09-2020", "19-09-2020", "20-05-2020", "20-06-2021", 
                                      "11-01-2021", "13-01-2021", "13-01-2021", "15-01-2021", "15-01-2021", "19-01-2021"))
# > test
#    my_groups measure       time
# 1          A      10 20-09-2020
# 2          A      20 25-09-2020
# 3          A       5 19-09-2020
# 4          B       2 20-05-2020
# 5          B      62 20-06-2021
# 6          C       2 11-01-2021
# 7          C       5 13-01-2021
# 8          C       4 13-01-2021
# 9          A       6 15-01-2021
# 10         A       7 15-01-2021
# 11         A      25 19-01-2021

test %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  group_by(my_groups) %>%
  summarise(mean_3 = rollapply(measure, 3, mean, by = 3, align = "left", partial = F),
            final_data = max(time))

# my_groups mean_3 final_data
#   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>     
# 1 A           12.7  25-09-2020
# 2 A           11.7  25-09-2020
# 3 C           3.67 13-01-2021
```

In the second line I wish the date was `19-01-2021`, and not the global maximum of group `A`, (`25-09-2020`).

Any hint on how I could do that?

Comment: What do you mean by 4 out of four?

Comment: It is a typo, sorry for that. I'd like to make the mean of 3 values for each group.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by that? If there are more than three rows per group then how do you choose which three to summarise? And what if there are fewer than three rows?

Comment: First I ordered the dataframe by date, then I took the mean of 3 values in a row in each group. If I have less than 3 values, I just disregard it.

Comment: Hi @DR15, First of all your time column is character instead of date. You will need to convert it to date. Also global maximum for group A is `19-01-2021` and not `25-09-2020`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 2 dplyr ways for you. Not happy with it because when the `rollapply` with `max` and dates doesn't find anything it in group B it uses a double by default which doesn't match the characters from group A and C.

Mutate:

```
test %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  group_by(my_groups) %>% 
  mutate(final = rollapply(time, 3, max, by = 3, fill = NA, align = "left", partial = F),
         mean_3 = rollapply(measure, 3, mean, by = 3, fill = NA, align = "left", partial = F)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(final)) %>% 
  select(my_groups, final, mean_3) %>% 
  arrange(my_groups)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   my_groups [2]
  my_groups final      mean_3
  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
1 A         19-01-2021  12.7 
2 A         25-09-2020  11.7 
3 C         13-01-2021   3.67
```

Summarise that doesn't summarise, but is a bit cleaner in code:

```
test %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  group_by(my_groups) %>% 
  summarise(final = rollapply(time, 3, max, by = 3, fill = NA, align = "left", partial = F),
         mean_3 = rollapply(measure, 3, mean, by = 3, fill = NA, align = "left", partial = F)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(final))

`summarise()` has grouped output by 'my_groups'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   my_groups [2]
  my_groups final      mean_3
  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
1 A         19-01-2021  12.7 
2 A         25-09-2020  11.7 
3 C         13-01-2021   3.67
```

**Edit:**

Added isa's solution from comment. `Partial = TRUE` does the trick:

```
test %>% 
  arrange(time) %>% 
  group_by(my_groups) %>% 
  summarise(mean_3 = rollapply(measure, 3, mean, by = 3, align = "left", partial = F), 
            final_data = rollapply(time, 3, max, by = 3, align = "left", partial = T))

`summarise()` has grouped output by 'my_groups'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   my_groups [2]
  my_groups mean_3 final_data
  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     
1 A          12.7  19-01-2021
2 A          11.7  25-09-2020
3 C           3.67 13-01-2021
```

Comment: `rollapply` with `max` doesn't work due to below reason

https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/zoo/html/rollapply.html See in Details section

To solve the issue we can use the below code by changing `partial` argument to TRUE

`test %>%`
`arrange(time) %>%`
`group_by(my_groups) %>%`
`summarise(mean_3 = rollapply(measure, 3, mean, by = 3, align = "left", partial = F),`
`final_data = rollapply(time, 3, max, by = 3, align = "left", partial = T))`

Comment: I don't know what happened, but the last approach doesn't work anymore. Using the same example, returns the following: `Error: Problem with summarise() column mean_3.
i mean_3 = rollapply(measure, 3, mean, by = 3, align = "left", partial = F).
x could not find function "rollapply"
i The error occurred in group 1: my_groups = "A"`

Comment: @DR15, run `library(zoo)` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

test = data.frame(my_groups = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C",  "A", "A", "A"),
                  measure = c(10, 20, 5, 2, 62 ,2, 5, 4, 6, 7, 25),
                  time= c("20-09-2020", "25-09-2020", "19-09-2020", "20-05-2020", "20-06-2021", 
                          "11-01-2021", "13-01-2021", "13-01-2021", "15-01-2021", "15-01-2021", "19-01-2021"))

test %>% 
  group_by(data.table::rleid(my_groups)) %>% 
  filter(n() == 3) %>% 
  summarise(
    groups = unique(my_groups), 
    mean_3 = mean(measure), final_data = max(time), .groups = "drop") %>%
  select(-1)

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   groups mean_3 final_data
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1 A       11.7  25-09-2020
#> 2 C        3.67 13-01-2021
#> 3 A       12.7  19-01-2021
```

**EDIT**

To allow for calculation of mean of 2 values, as asked for in a comment below by the OP, I revised my code, using `data.table::frollmean` and `data.table::frollapply`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

n <- 2 # choose the number with which to calculate the mean

test %>% 
  group_by(rleid(my_groups)) %>% 
  summarise(
    groups = unique(my_groups), 
    mean_n = frollmean(measure, n), final_data = frollapply(dmy(time), n, max) %>% 
      as_date(origin = lubridate::origin), .groups = "drop") %>%
  drop_na(mean_n) %>% select(-1)

#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>   groups mean_n final_data
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <date>    
#> 1 A        15   2020-09-25
#> 2 A        12.5 2020-09-25
#> 3 B        32   2021-06-20
#> 4 C         3.5 2021-01-13
#> 5 C         4.5 2021-01-13
#> 6 A         6.5 2021-01-15
#> 7 A        16   2021-01-19
```

Comment: Interesting! I'm going to test this solution too, because in my real case I have other variables to keep in the final result.

Comment: Please, be aware, @DR15, that I have meanwhile edited a very small detail of my solution.

Comment: I have reached a solution -- the current one -- that is slightly more efficient than the previous ones, @DR15.

Comment: If I use the same logic, but now taking mean for 2 values, and not 3 anymore, this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Well that was not made explicit when you asked your question! However, I think that you can adapt my code to make it work in the case of the mean of 2 values. In any case, the solution proposed by @phiver maybe works also in the case of the mean of 2 values (but I have not checked that).

Comment: My edited solution works for the case of calculating the mean of 2 values. In truth, it works for calculating the mean of an arbitrary number of values (by setting parameter `n`), @DR15.